# Limit WMTS zoom level in QGIS

Tags: qgis, zoom, wmts

I am using the [Ordnance Survey Maps API WMTS](https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/wmts/technicalSpecification) in QGIS. This WMTS provides tiles up to zoom level 16 for free, but charges above this. Can I limit QGIS to only attempt to fetch tiles below this threshold, despite the WMTS metadata reporting that higher zoom level tiles are available?

I have tried to adjust the Z maximum value in the Layer Properties dialogue, but this doesn't seem to prevent the higher zoom levels being requested (as reported by the QGIS Network Monitor).

[image: Limiting the Z maximum in the Layer Properties dialogue]

The best I can do is set up scale dependent visibility to make the layer disappear when I overzoom. Is this the only approach?

I'm on 3.28.10-Firenze on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use WMTS connection but use the XYZ (or rather ZXY) connection that is also supported from endpoint https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy/layer/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png?key= as documented in https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/wmts/technicalSpecification.

For the XYZ connections the min/max zoom levels can be set with the QGIS connection editor

[image]

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! Whilst it solves my problem, it doesn't answer my question, which I'm still interested in, so I will not mark this as solved just yet in case there are other answers for doing this for a WMTS.

Comment: This is certainly a very useful workaround even if it doesn't quite answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The following may or may not work. I could not test it because I do not have an api key to that Ordnance Survey service.

This option requires some command line magic with GDAL. The GDAL WMTS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wmts.html supports open option ZOOM_LEVEL.

> ZOOM_LEVEL=value: Index of the maximum zoom level tile matrix to use
> for the full resolution GDAL dataset (lower zoom levels will be used
> for overviews). The first one (ie the one of lower resolution) is
> indexed 0. Mutually exclusive with TILEMATRIX. If not specified the
> last tile matrix, i.e. the one with the best resolution, is selected.

For using GDAL WMTS with QGIS user must first create a XML file as documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wmts.html#generation-of-wmts-service-description-xml-file

With a proper key and layer name this command should create a file named os_wmts.xml.

```
gdal_translate "WMTS:https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/wmts?request=getcapabilities&key=,layer=layer" os_wmts.xml -of WMTS
```

Open the os_wmts.xml file with text editor and add

```
<ZoomLevel>16</ZoomLevel>
```

It is also possible the the ZoomLevel gets added automatically with a modified command

```
gdal_translate "WMTS:https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/wmts?request=getcapabilities&key=,layer=layer" -oo ZOOM_LEVEL=16 os_wmts.xml -of WMTS
```

Test that the XML file works with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo os_wmts.xml
```

If it works with gdalinfo it should work also with QGIS. The XML file is not used through WMS/WMTS connection but through Add raster layer - file

[image]

Comment: Please test. If it does not work I will delete the answer.